# Isometric embedding of the 2-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

Can anyone give me a hint or a reference that would help to understand the following result :

The only compact $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-submanifold  of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of constant curvature $\frac{1}{R}$ is the sphere of radius $R$

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

See p. 61 here: http://math.berkeley.edu/~reshetik/140/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf